# Symfony2 / friendsOfSymfony/UserBundle

Tags: symfony, redirect, credentials

I'm using FOS/Userbundle for login process of my application.
This application is the back-end part of my work. The front end one can be on another server.
Login works correctly when user is authenticated. My problem is when user is not recognized. In this case, Symfony redirects response to an url of my back-end when I want it to go back to my front-end url. I have not found neither in Symfony doc nor various forums elements for progress on this issue.

Thank you for your help.

Caplande

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can configure, in security.yml , the firewall which is used by fosUserBundle, and tell it to redirect in case of success but also in case of error.

The idea is, in case of error to redirect the user to an action on your app which is not under your fosuserbundle firewall rules.

This action should finally redirect the non authenticated user to your frontend url.

here is an example :

in your security.yml,

```
security:
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            failure_path:                   YOUR_REDIRECTING_PATH
            failure_forward:                true
```

you needto finish, to make a route readable anonimously in you app to redirect to your frontend app.

for more information : https://symfony2-document.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/security/form_login.html

Hope this helps